# Ruby on Rails - AJAX request not working (cross-origin), tried everything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cors, same-origin-policy

(sorry for bad english)
I try to execute an ajax request but it doesn't work due to same-origin policy. My application is not deployed yet and I use Ruby on Rails 3.2.3 with Unicorn server.

The AJAX request is in an asset javascript file and I call it in a view. when I try to get the datas from the AJAX requests, the console says 
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url]. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

I tried everything :

- Use jsonp in ajax request : console.log said syntax error
- Use rack cors, with making everything said on the readme (https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), but it didn't work, still the same message in the console (restatring server or not)
- Try some syntaxes for rack-cors said on every post about it in stack overflow I could find, I tried this :

application.rb :

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options], expose: :location
  end
```

but it didn't work, and I tried this in config.ru

```
use Rack::Cors do

  # allow all origins in development
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:3000'
    resource '*',
         :headers => :any,
         :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options]
  end
end
```

I tried this code with "origins 'localhost:3000'" ans with "origins '*'" but none of them worked, I didn't forgot the "require 'rack/cors'"

I am desperte, could you help me please ?

Comment: What browser are you using?  Chrome blocks this type of behavior internally.  Running in your bash
$open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
will turn off this feature.

Comment: I use firefox, but the application needs to work in chrome, too.

Comment: I have to ask:  Did you restart your rails server after amending your application.rb file?

Comment: Yes I restart after every change

Comment: If you still need help with this, try making sure you have all of the HTTP verbs covered in the methods array. If that still doesn't work, post your controller code. You might need `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` in there. If that doesn't work, check your routes and namespacing.

Comment: thanks a lot but before I quit the society (my work was done) they said that it was normal that the cross rigin didn't work (why ? I don't know)

Answer (score 0):

It is almost undoubtedly that you aren't defining the proper headers to allow access.  The following walk-through should get you going:

http://dotnet-concept.com/Tip/2015/3/5798824/Cross-Origin-Request-Blocked-The-Same-Origin-Policy-disallows-reading-the-remote-resource-This-can-be-fixed-by-moving-the-resource-to-the-same-domain-or-enabling-CORS-

Comment: I set the same headers as described in the tutorial, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation that was resolved using `rack-cors`

Gemefile:

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

application.rb:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Don't forget to restart your rails server!

EDIT:

It just occurred to me, that this will only work in production if you are using your app server as the web server as well.  If you are using Nginx or Apache as your web server, then your static assets will be served from it.  You will have to enable CORS on Nginx/Apache.

Comment: so that's why it didn't work for me ! I already used rack-cors (exactly the same code) but how can I make it work in development mode ?

Comment: I just test it and it still dosen't work even in production mode =/